# Why is my onclick function not called?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
?php foreach($participants as $participant) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $participant['Vorname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $participant['Auto'] . "<img id=$participant[name_id] onclick='deleteDriver()' class='delete' src='img/tonne.gif' align='right' data-url='backend/queries.php?decision=deleteDriver&id=".$participant['name_id']."'/></td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>

        function deleteDriver()
        {
            var dataString = "decision=deleteDriver";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'queries.php',
                data: dataString
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

When I push the button the function is not called.  Why?

Comment: `?php` is not a valid php opening tag. Where is the start tag for `<script>` ?

Comment: And you have HTML content inside `<script>` tags, some many things are wrong with above code

Comment: You have add extra `}` in your js code as well. And missed `;` after `AJAX` function end.

Comment: `Console` inside the _function_

Comment: tryed all still doesent work

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `<script>` open tag before `function deleteDriver()`. Please add and retry. Try as below :

```
<?php
foreach($participants as $participant) {

  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $participant['Vorname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $participant['Auto'] . "<img id='".$participant['name_id']."' onclick='deleteDriver()' class='delete' src='img/tonne.gif' align='right' data-url='backend/queries.php?decision=deleteDriver&id=".$participant['name_id']."'/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
<script>
        function deleteDriver()
        {
            var dataString = "decision=deleteDriver";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'queries.php',
                data: dataString
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot about `echo` and the HTML content inside the `<script>`, go over the code again.

Answer (score 1):

try with this code.

```
<?php
    foreach($participants as $participant) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $participant['Vorname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a onclick='deleteDriver()'>" . $participant['Auto'] . "<img id=$participant[name_id] class='delete' src='img/tonne.gif' align='right' data-url='backend/queries.php?decision=deleteDriver&id=".$participant['name_id']."'/></a></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
      <script>
            function deleteDriver()
            {
                var dataString = "decision=deleteDriver";
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'queries.php',
                    data: dataString

                })
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: the link is now on my text but i want it on my img